# Parsing double[] within JSON array in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

Im new to android all i have used previously is that i get JSON Array from server and parsed JSON objects like following,,

```
JSONObject objResponse = new JSONObject(retResult);
String objString = objResponse.toString();
String strResponse = null;
if ((objString.contains(getString(R.string.response)))
            || objString.contains((String) getString(R.string.response)
                    .toLowerCase())
            || (objString.contains((String) getString(R.string.response)
                    .toUpperCase()))) {
strResponse = objResponse.getString(getString(R.string.response));
} else {
    strResponse = "";
}
```

Help me to parse the following JSON return from server,,,

```
{
  "iapStandardHeight":[
    [
      53.4,
      65.3,
      71.6,
      76.2,
      80.2,
      83.9,
      87.3,
      90.5,
      93.6,
      95.7,
      98.3,
      100.8,
      103.1,
      107.3,
      111.2,
      115,
      118.7,
      125.9,
      129.2,
      132.3,
      135.6,
      138.9,
      142.1,
      145,
      147.7,
      150.4,
      153.2,
      156.3,
      159.8,
      163.4,
      167,
      170.6,
      174.1,
      177,
      179.1,
      180.6,
      181.5,
      182.1,
      182.6,
      182.9,
      183.1,
      183.3
    ],
    [
      51.2,
      62.8,
      69.1,
      73.5,
      77.4,
      80.9,
      84.1,
      87.1,
      89.9,
      91.8,
      94.2,
      96.5,
      98.6,
      102.5,
      106.2,
      109.6,
      113.1,
      118.5,
      121.6,
      124.6,
      127.7,
      130.8,
      133.8,
      136.6,
      139.1,
      141.6,
      144.2,
      147,
      150.2,
      153.4,
      156.7,
      160.1,
      163.6,
      166.7,
      169.2,
      171,
      172.3,
      173.1,
      173.7,
      174.2,
      174.5,
      174.7
    ],
    [
      49.9,
      61.4,
      67.6,
      72,
      75.7,
      79.1,
      82.3,
      85.1,
      87.8,
      89.6,
      91.9,
      94.1,
      96.1,
      99.9,
      103.3,
      106.7,
      110,
      114.9,
      118,
      120.9,
      123.9,
      126.9,
      129.8,
      132.4,
      134.9,
      137.2,
      139.7,
      142.4,
      145.3,
      148.3,
      151.5,
      154.8,
      158.2,
      161.4,
      164.1,
      166.1,
      167.5,
      168.5,
      169.2,
      169.7,
      170,
      170.4
    ],
    [
      48.6,
      60.1,
      66.2,
      70.5,
      74.1,
      77.4,
      80.4,
      83.2,
      85.8,
      87.4,
      89.6,
      91.7,
      93.6,
      97.2,
      100.5,
      103.7,
      106.8,
      111.4,
      114.4,
      117.2,
      120.1,
      123,
      125.7,
      128.3,
      130.6,
      132.9,
      135.2,
      137.7,
      140.5,
      143.3,
      146.2,
      149.4,
      152.8,
      156,
      158.9,
      161.1,
      162.7,
      163.8,
      164.6,
      165.1,
      165.5,
      165.9
    ],
    [
      46.3,
      57.6,
      63.6,
      67.7,
      71.3,
      74.4,
      77.2,
      79.7,
      82.1,
      83.5,
      85.5,
      87.4,
      89.1,
      92.4,
      95.4,
      98.4,
      101.2,
      104.7,
      107.5,
      110.1,
      112.7,
      115.4,
      117.9,
      120.1,
      122.2,
      124.3,
      126.3,
      128.4,
      130.8,
      133.1,
      135.6,
      138.5,
      141.7,
      145.1,
      148.2,
      150.8,
      152.8,
      154.1,
      155.1,
      155.8,
      156.3,
      156.7
    ]
  ],
  "iapStandardWeight":[
    [
      4.3,
      7.9,
      9.7,
      10.9,
      11.8,
      12.7,
      13.5,
      14.3,
      15.1,
      15.9,
      16.6,
      17.3,
      18,
      19.4,
      20.9,
      22.3,
      28.6,
      31.3,
      33.9,
      36.6,
      39.4,
      42.5,
      45.8,
      48.8,
      51.8,
      54.8,
      57.9,
      61.4,
      65.3,
      69.1,
      72.8,
      76.5,
      80.2,
      83.6,
      86.8,
      89.4,
      91.6,
      93.4,
      94.9,
      96.2,
      97.3,
      98.3
    ],
    [
      3.7,
      6.9,
      8.5,
      9.6,
      10.4,
      11.1,
      11.8,
      12.5,
      13.1,
      13.8,
      14.4,
      15,
      15.6,
      16.7,
      17.8,
      19,
      20.8,
      22.5,
      24.1,
      25.8,
      27.5,
      29.4,
      31.5,
      33.4,
      35.3,
      37.3,
      39.5,
      42.1,
      45,
      47.9,
      50.9,
      53.8,
      56.7,
      59.4,
      61.8,
      63.9,
      65.6,
      67,
      68.2,
      69.2,
      70.1,
      71
    ],
    [
      3.3,
      6.4,
      7.9,
      8.9,
      9.6,
      10.3,
      10.9,
      11.5,
      12.2,
      12.7,
      13.3,
      13.8,
      14.3,
      15.3,
      16.3,
      17.3,
      18.4,
      19.8,
      21.1,
      22.5,
      23.9,
      25.4,
      27,
      28.6,
      30.1,
      31.7,
      33.5,
      35.6,
      38,
      40.5,
      43,
      45.6,
      48.1,
      50.6,
      52.8,
      54.7,
      56.3,
      57.7,
      58.8,
      59.8,
      60.7,
      61.5
    ],
    [
      3,
      5.9,
      7.4,
      8.3,
      9,
      9.6,
      10.1,
      10.7,
      11.3,
      11.8,
      12.3,
      12.8,
      13.2,
      14.1,
      15,
      15.9,
      16.5,
      17.7,
      18.8,
      19.9,
      21.1,
      22.3,
      23.6,
      24.9,
      26.1,
      27.3,
      28.8,
      30.4,
      32.4,
      34.4,
      36.6,
      38.8,
      41,
      43.3,
      45.4,
      47.2,
      48.8,
      50.1,
      51.2,
      52.1,
      53.1,
      53.9
    ],
    [
      2.5,
      5.1,
      6.4,
      7.2,
      7.8,
      8.4,
      8.9,
      9.3,
      9.8,
      10.2,
      10.7,
      11.1,
      11.4,
      12.2,
      12.9,
      13.6,
      13.8,
      14.7,
      15.5,
      16.2,
      17,
      17.9,
      18.7,
      19.5,
      20.3,
      21.1,
      21.9,
      22.9,
      24.2,
      25.5,
      26.9,
      28.5,
      30.3,
      32.2,
      34.1,
      35.8,
      37.3,
      38.6,
      39.7,
      40.7,
      41.6,
      42.5
    ]
  ],
  "iapStandardAgeDiff":[
    "0.0",
    "0.3",
    "0.6",
    "0.9",
    "1.0",
    "1.3",
    "1.6",
    "1.9",
    "2.0",
    "2.3",
    "2.6",
    "2.9",
    "3.0",
    "3.6",
    "4.0",
    "4.6",
    "5.0",
    "6.0",
    "6.6",
    "7.0",
    "7.6",
    "8.0",
    "8.6",
    "9.0",
    "9.6",
    "10.0",
    "10.6",
    "11.0",
    "11.6",
    "12.0",
    "12.6",
    "13.0",
    "13.6",
    "14.0",
    "14.6",
    "15.0",
    "15.6",
    "16.0",
    "16.6",
    "17.0",
    "17.6",
    "18.0"
  ],
  "gender":"Boys",
  "dob":"2000/2/5",
  "IAPDetails":{
    "heightInCms":[
      152.401853206535
    ],
    "heightInFt":[
      5
    ],
    "heightInCmsDate":[
      "2014/1/25"
    ],
    "heightInFtDate":[
      "2014/1/25"
    ],
    "weightInKg":[
      45
    ],
    "weightInLbs":[
      99.20799000000001
    ],
    "weightInKgDate":[
      "2014/1/25"
    ],
    "weightInLbsDate":[
      "2014/1/25"
    ]
  },
  "response":"success"
}
```

help will be thankfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `iapStandardHeight`looks to be a jagged array. This looks to be the most complicated bit of the json you are receiving. Below is code for creating a jagged double array from the json you posted. If you need more help, just add a comment.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

JSONArray outerArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("iapStandardHeight");
double[][] result = new double[outerArray.length()][];

for(int i = 0; i < outerArray.length(); i++){

    JSONArray innerArray = outerArray.getJSONArray(i);
    double[] innerResult = new double[innerArray.length()];

    for(int j = 0; j < innerArray.length(); j++){               
        innerResult[j] = innerArray.getDouble(j);               
    }

    result[i] = innerResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
try {
                        JSONObject objResponse = new JSONObject(retResult);
                        JSONArray arr = objResponse.getJSONArray("iapStandardHeight");
                        for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++){
                            JSONArray arr2 = arr.getJSONArray(i);
                            for(int j=0; j<arr2.length(); j++){
                                double value = arr2.getDouble(j);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```