# How to parse Double array JSON

Tags: android, json

In my application I'm trying to parse This structure type Json value. Did any of you guys face this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Main problem is double **`[[`**

```
[
  [
    {
      "nid": "29",
      "vid": "30",
      "type": "oa_discussion_post",
      "language": "und",
      "title": "We want to hear from you.",
      "uid": "1",
      "status": "1",
      "created": "1441316801",
      "changed": "1442461699",
      "comment": "2",
      "promote": "0",
      "sticky": "0",
      "tnid": "0",
      "translate": "0",
      "uuid": "b9cb0351-5dbc-4ef1-8f8c-5570b66a2339"
    }
  ]
]
```

Here is my approach:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonData);
for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);

    String userType=e.getString("vid");
    String topLine=e.getString("type");
}
```

Where is my error?

Comment: This complete solution link might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22014966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a nested array inside the top level array

```
 for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++) {
   JSONArray nestedJsonArray = json.optJSONArray(i);
   if (nestedJsonArray != null) {
        for(int j=0;j<nestedJsonArray.length();j++) {
              // use j and nestedJsonArray to retrieve the JSONObect
              HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject e = nestedJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                String userType=e.optString("vid");
                String topLine=e.optString("type");
        }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have another `JSONArray`but you use `JSONObject`. Just do

```
JSONArray firstArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
JSONArray secondArray = firstArray.getJSONArray(0);
JSONObject jsonObject = secondArray.getJSONObject(0);

//Do want you want with your jsonObject
String userType = jsonObject .getString("vid");
String topLine = jsonObject .getString("type");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an object in an array in an array.

You have to select the first array in it instead of selecting the JSONObject directly. After selecting the second JSONArray, then select your JSONObject using `getJSONObject(0);`